# Can't include header file

Tags: c++, qt

I need to include header files from sqlite3x library (or from sqlite) in my project. I've just created new project in Qt Creator and added the following lines in .pro-file:

> INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(D:/libs/libsqlite3x-2007.10.18) INCLUDEPATH +=
>   $$quote(D:/libs/sqlite-amalgamation-3071502)

Then i've tried to include

```
#include <sqlite3x.hpp>
```

and compile.

> Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory

Why?

If i write

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

i've got the same error.

When i write this preprocessing directive, Qt Creator gives me an autocompletion and if i press F2 on this line it'll open this file.

http://pastie.org/7670341
http://pastie.org/7670574

Comment: Can you add output of dir or ls -l command proving that this file exists?

Comment: @PiotrNycz Done - http://pastie.org/7670341

Comment: Can you show the compiler command line from the build log?

Comment: @Michael Burr Done - http://pastie.org/7670574

Comment: Have you re-run qmake? And are the two `INCLUDEPATH` items on separate lines (it's not clear that they are in the question formatting)?

Comment: @Michael Burr How can i do it?

Comment: Menu item: `Build | Run qmake`

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(D:/libs/libsqlite3x-2007.10.18) $$quote(D:/libs/sqlite-amalgamation-3071502)
```

If you see http://pastie.org/7670574
these are the include directives

> -I"D:\libs\libsqlite3x-2007.10.18" -I"D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtSql" -I"D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"release" -I"." -I"." -I"D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010"

If you look - you don't see `D:/libs/sqlite-amalgamation-3071502`. Your build tool is not picking up the directory & adding it to the `INCLUDEPATH` because only it picks up only one `INCLUDEPATH` line - so both to the same `INCLUDEPATH` line with a space separating them.

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov What's your make output with the above?